# Show d3 node text only on hover

Tags: d3.js, mouseover, nodes

I'm trying to only show the node text on mouseover. When I mouseover the node, I have the  opacity for the svg circle changing, but only the text for the first node showing up. I've figured out that this is because of how I'm using the select element, but I can't figure out how to pull the correct text for the node that I'm hovering on. Here's what I currently have.

```
node.append("svg:circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) { return radius_scale(parseInt(d.size)); })
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return d.fill; })
    .attr("stroke", function(d) { return d.stroke; })
    .on('mouseover', function(d){
        d3.select(this).style({opacity:'0.8'})
        d3.select("text").style({opacity:'1.0'});
                })
    .on('mouseout', function(d){
      d3.select(this).style({opacity:'0.0',})
      d3.select("text").style({opacity:'0.0'});
    })
    .call(force.drag);
```

Comment: You can also just have a single text box, and move it to the correct location when you mouse-over the points.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you use `d3.select` you're searching the entire DOM for `<text>` elements and selecting the first one.  To select specific text  nodes you either need a more specific selector (e.g. `#textnode1`) or you need to use a subselection to constrain the selection under a particular parent node. For example, if the `<text>` element lived directly under the node in your example you could use:

```
.on('mouseover', function(d){
    var nodeSelection = d3.select(this).style({opacity:'0.8'});
    nodeSelection.select("text").style({opacity:'1.0'});
})
```

Comment: The text element lived under the node itself, so I was able to get it working by using the code you provided for mouseover and mouseout of the node itself.